# Updating Attribute from Journey Builder Wait By Attribute Activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, leads

My Journey has a Salesforce Data Entry Event and a Wait By Attribute activity containing an attribute date from Salesforce Lead record. The moment the Journey reaches the Wait By Attribute activity, is it possible to update the attribute value by updating the referenced value from the Salesforce Lead record?

My client wants to skip waiting time to proceed succeeding activities if specific users accomplishes something (my solution for this is updating the referenced attribute value from the specific users Salesforce Lead record)

I've tried it already but I still couldn't make it work. In the hopes of maybe I'm just doing it wrong, I just want to confirm if this is actually possible. If not, is there any other possible way I can meet my clients specifications?

Edit: @razor confirmed to me that Wait By Attribute activities will use the referenced date the moment it is entered and it cannot be updated. Hence I am unable to change the reference date and skip the waiting activity. Is there any other solution for skipping waiting activities?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible but you have to do it in Salesforce.

I hope you are using contact data for the wait by attribute in journey.

As per your use case (when specific users accomplishes something) just change the wait by attribute to some past date or remove the wait date itself using trigger in salesforce.

Since it is past or without the wait date, journey builder will skip the wait by attribute and enter into the next activity.

Reference: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_wait_for_a_date_based_on_an_attribute_value.htm&type=5

Comment: I just want to confirm if it's possible to update the attribute from Salesforce even though the waiting activity already started. I tried your suggestion and removed the referenced date from my Lead record. I was expecting it to skip the wait activity but nothing changed. I'm guessing that the waiting time will be permanently set on the date referenced the moment the activity is entered? Is this correct?

Reference: From you reference: " The wait time is determined at the moment the contact reaches the wait activity."

Comment: @justinPCM that's correct. You have do an update before it reaches wait by attribute.Once the contact reaches the wait activity you can no longer change it.